# Have selenium interact with safari "store password" popup?

Tags: selenium, safari

I have a selenium test that tests the login of a site through a browser instance available on a selenium-grid. This works fine when using a firefox browser instance but when using safari the test cannot get through the entire test because safari pops up a window with the question "Would you like me to save this password".

It doesn't seem to appear as a window_handle nor as an alert. How can I have selenium dismiss this safari popup and continue its test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. WebDriver cannot interact with browser and/or OS specific dialogs.

You probably have two choices:

1. Save/dismiss the password manually the first time you run through the test, then [reuse the profile every time](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Safari_specific).
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> programatically via your programming language. You didn't specify which one you're using, so here's a Java example:

   ```
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
   ```

   It's a hack, but it's reliable and it's what I've been doing to overcome similar issues.

Comment: How do you reuse the profile for safari? @Petr Janeček

Comment: @Mr.O I do not know anymore, sorry. This answer is 5 years old and I would hope that perhaps new drivers can automatically handle such problems? Anyway, I took a look into [`SafariOptions`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/safari/SafariOptions.html) and unfortunately there's no profile handling option (unlike FirefoxOptions which can explicitly handle profiles). Sorry.

Comment: it is alright. Yes, I checked the same with SafariOptions. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it uses JavaScript to change the password to text, and this stops the pop-up:

```
driver.executeScript("Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach(function(e){e.type=e.type=='password'?'text':e.type;});");
```

Comment: Testing this with latest driver does not work, it asks for any input named "password". This certainly used to work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can selectively disable password capture for specific domains. You can also disable password capture altogether by clearing the auto-fill option for username/password.